# How can I center image in Bootstrap 4, with fixed-top navbar, and without vertical scrolling?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I'd like to achieve the following result:
[image: ideal layout]

Requirements:

1. Image should be responsive
2. Fixed-top navbar has to stay
3. No vertical scrolling
4. Footer has to stay, too (preferably on the bottom)

I spent the whole day trying to figure out it without results.
I tried this approach:

```
https://codepen.io/Codewife_101/pen/rpvdPq
```

but 'align-self-center' caused the vertical scrolling in my website.
It doesn't look good, in particular on mobile devices.

I VERSION:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
      <title>Red Logo Website</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css">
      <!--Material Design Icons-->
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
          rel="stylesheet">
      <!--adding Roboto different styles-->
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-light fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
          <img src="img/navbar_red_logo.32x32.png" class="img-fluid" alt="red-logo">
          <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav2"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav2">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link font-weight-bold" href="">Brand Name</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#about">About</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#about">Contact</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>

      <!-- 1. JUMBOTRON -->
      <section id="showcase">
        <div class="container h-100">
          <div class="row h-100 justify-content-center align-self-center">
            <img src="img/red_logo.svg" class="img-fluid" alt="Red logo">
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>


      <!--FOOTER-->
      <footer id="main-footer" class="text-center">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
            <p class="text-muted">Copyright &copy; 2017 <img src="img/navbar_red_logo.32x32.png" class="img-fluid" alt="red-logo"> RedDesign LLC</p>      
          </div>
        </div>
      </footer>


      <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
      <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I also tried this approach:

```
https://codepen.io/Codewife_101/pen/eyVxre
```

II VERSION:

```
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-light fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
      <img src="img/navbar_red_logo.32x32.png" class="img-fluid" alt="red-logo">
      <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav2"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav2">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link font-weight-bold" href="">Brand Name</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#about">About</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#about">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <!-- 1. JUMBOTRON -->
  <section id="showcase">
    <div class="container h-100">
      <div class="row h-100 justify-content-center align-items-center">
        <img src="https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/all-images-public/red_logo.svg" class="img-fluid" alt="Red logo">
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>


  <!--FOOTER-->
  <footer id="main-footer" class="text-center">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
        <p class="text-muted">Copyright &copy; 2018 <img src="img/navbar_red_logo.32x32.png" class="img-fluid" alt="red-logo"> RedDesign LLC</p>      
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>
```

It doesn't center vertically. I'm open to any suggestions/solutions.
Anyone? I would be very grateful for any tips.

At first glance, my question looks like a duplicate, but when you look deeper, you'll see my situation varies. Besides, my reputation is too low to write comments on somebody else's question.

Comment: Just a hint: you may get more help if people don't have to open a link to see the code you are using. Use the Snippet Editor and Copy/Paste over the relevant information.

Answer (score 0):

use CSS

css property `position:fixed` then
your header

```
div id = "NAVBAR"
```

and your footer too

```
div id = "FOOTER"
```

In your css:

```
    #NAVBAR{
    bottom:0
           }

   #FOOTER{
    top:0
           }
```

you must set the height off the body accoding to you screen resolution for you   to not have an scrolling effect.

Comment: It doesn't work. Check it out: [link] (https://codepen.io/Codewife_101/pen/GydGoG) and this one doesn't work too: [link] (https://codepen.io/Codewife_101/pen/YYLvpe)

Comment: @Codewife_101 use this 

#NAVBAR{
    top:0;
  position:fixed;
}

#FOOTER{
    bottom:0;
    position:fixed;
}
} and sorry #nvabar css was top:0 and footer was the bottom sorry you can try it now

Comment: Still, it doesn't solve the problem. I guess I have to rewrite it using flex.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this, it revolves around dynamic height thanks to calc and vh(viewport height)

```css
nav, footer{
  max-height: 50px;
}

body,html, section{
  height: 100%;
}
section{
  display: flex !important;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}


section img{
  object-fit: contain;
  height: calc(100vh - 150px) !important; 
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">

  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>

 <ul class="navbar-nav nav">
   <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link">Link</a></li>
   <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link">Link</a></li>
   <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link">Link</a></li>
 </ul>
</nav>

<section>
  <img src="http://www.tandemconstruction.com/sites/default/files/styles/project_slider_main/public/images/project-images/IMG-Residence-1_0.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid">
</section>

<footer class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom text-center">
   <p class="text-muted navbar-brand">Copyright &copy; 2018 RedDesign LLC</p> 
</footer>
```

Comment: Why did you put 'navbar' classes into footer? It doesn't look correct to me. Besides, the class 'img-responsive' doesn't exist in Bootstrap 4. Now, it is called 'img-fluid'. [link] (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/images/#responsive-images)

Comment: Footer as you are planing it is indeed a navigation bar! And sorry about the img-fluid. If you don't feel like using the nav classes in the footer, simply set the height to 50px and position fixed, bottom 0.

Comment: The more I care about the image. Your code doesn't center it vertically.

Comment: Please check again, I was styling it based on the img-responsive class, had to change the css since I changed the class to img-fluid

Comment: You used the wrong version of Bootstrap. My questions refers to Bootstrap 4.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed your code. Below is the working version.

The problem was a simple beginner mistake: You had the image in a row but not in a column. Bootstrap rows and columns are designed to work together. So, whenever you create a `.row` you must create at least one `.col` inside that row. That usually fixes all of the problems.

Here's the working version of your code:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">


<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-light fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <img src="img/navbar_red_logo.32x32.png" class="img-fluid" alt="red-logo">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav2"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav2">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link font-weight-bold" href="">Brand Name</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#about">About</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#about">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

<!-- 1. JUMBOTRON -->
<section id="showcase">
    <div class="container" style="height: 100vh;">
        <div class="row h-100">
            <div class="col align-self-center">
                <img src="https://picsum.photos/440/" class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block">
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<!--FOOTER-->
<footer id="main-footer" class="text-center fixed-bottom">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <p class="text-muted">Copyright &copy; 2018 <img src="img/navbar_red_logo.32x32.png" class="img-fluid" alt="logo"> RedDesign LLC</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-a5N7Y/aK3qNeh15eJKGWxsqtnX/wWdSZSKp+81YjTmS15nvnvxKHuzaWwXHDli+4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: It doesn't solve my problem. The content isn't centered vertically. I used flexbox in this example. My understanding of flexbox in bootstrap is that you either put the content in a flex row or a flex column; you cannot put the flex column in the flex row. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I now fixed the issue and updated my code snippet. Check it out. It's now vertically and horizontally centered. There seemed to be an issue with your SVG, so I used a different image instead.

Comment: I tried your approach. Unfortunately, it didn't work either. It messed up my layout. Moreover, it didn't look good on mobile screens. I guess, I have to change my website layout because I'm not able to achieve what I want:(

Comment: Hmm... Are you sure it wasn't a caching issue or something?? Because I sure did test on all possible screens from the smallest 320px to the 4K widescreen size and on all, it looked exactly like the image you posted.

Comment: I had also measured the distance left and right + top and bottom to make sure it was really centered. That's where I noticed that there must be some weird issue with your SVG. When I replaced your SVG with a square image, it was perfectly centered (vertically and horizontally) but with your SVG it's a bit off-center horizontally. So, it can only be the SVG that's causing an issue there and not the layout code.